# JQuery Clone is Not retaining radio and select states

Tags: jquery, clone

When the copy link is clicked I am cloning the current row. When a new row is created the old state of the radio buttons are not retained.

I need to clone the current row and it should retain the input elements state of the old row as well.

**Code**

```js
$("#MyLastOrder tr .BtnPlus").click(function () {

$($(this).parent().parent()).clone(true, true).appendTo("#MyLastOrder");
var totalRows = document.getElementById("totalrows").value;
var qtyrow = "totalqty_" + eval(parseInt(totalRows) + 1);
var weightrow = "weight_" + eval(parseInt(totalRows) + 1);
var brandrow = "br_" + eval(parseInt(totalRows) + 1);

$("#MyLastOrder tr:last").find("input:radio").each(function () {

    var curName = $(this).attr('name');
    console.log("curname" + $(this).attr('name') + curName.substr(0, 2));
    $(this).attr('name', function (_, id) {
        var currentNameAttr = $(this).attr('name');
        if (curName.substr(0, 2) == "br") {
            $(this).attr('name', brandrow);
        }
        if (curName.substr(0, 2) == "we") {
            $(this).attr('name', weightrow);
        }

    });

});

$("#MyLastOrder tr:last").find("select").each(function () {
    var curName = $(this).attr('name');
    console.log("curname" + $(this).attr('name') + curName.substr(0, 2));
    $(this).attr('name', function (_, id) {
        var currentNameAttr = $(this).attr('name');
        if (curName.substr(0, 3) == "tot") {
            $(this).attr('name', qtyrow);
        }
    });

});
var incTotalRows = parseInt(totalRows) + 1;
document.getElementById("totalrows").value = incTotalRows;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="MyLastOrder">
<thead>
    <tr id="header1">
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="br_1" value="13" type="radio" checked="true">&nbsp;xyz<br>
            <input name="br_1" value="16" type="radio">&nbsp;xyz<br>
            <input name="br_1" value="17" type="radio">&nbsp;xyz<br>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="weight_1" value="1" type="radio">&nbsp;1gm<br>
            <input name="weight_1" value="2" type="radio" checked="">&nbsp;2gm<br>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="totalqty_1">
                <option selected="">1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
                <option>9</option>
                <option>10</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        </td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="BtnPlus"><img src="images/copyitem.png" title="Copy"></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="totalrows1" id="totalrows" value="2">
<!--this hidden is to act as counter and increment input elements name when cloning. this will be dynamically updated when a row is cloned.-->
```

Comment: Your Stack Snippet doesn't work. Clicking the button doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: While [dfsq](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27588737/1960455) already answered your question, why do you think that `eval` should be used here `eval(parseInt(totalRows)+1)`?  While `eval` should be never used in regular code, it does not make any sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't retain state of previous rows because you append new row with radio buttons having the same names as in previous row. So previous get unchecked of course.

What you want to do is to clone row first, then find radio buttons in the *clone* row, change names, and after that append cloned row.

```
var $clone = $($(this).parent().parent()).clone(true, true);

$clone.find(":radio").each(function () {
    // previous code
});

// and later
$clone.appendTo("#MyLastOrder");
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q1wphkpb/

Comment: Thanks dfsq it saves my time. Thanks for the code in fiddle.